# Ansible: Use newline character in multiline string

Tags: ansible

I'm using a win_lineinfile module and trying to use manual newline characters. It works just fine if the line argument of the module is only on one line but the moment I use multiline it breaks.

I'm trying to do this

```
- name: Something
  win_lineinfile:
    path: some_path
    line: |
      firstline\r\n
      secondline
```

but it doesn't work.
This does but I lose the ability of using multiline string.

```
- name: Something
  win_lineinfile:
    path: some_path
    line: firstline\r\nsecondline
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you're trying to use a literal `\r\n` in a multiline block. What do you expect the file to contain after this task runs?

Comment: It also goes against any sane definition of "line" in a file if it contains multiple lineS, as is also addressed by the fine manual: "This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only."

Answer (score 1):

In YAML [escape sequences are only interpreted in double-quoted scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#57-escaped-characters).

An easy way to have newlines in a YAML block scalar is to set variable containing the newline character, in Ansible typically like:

```
$ cat group_vars/all/vars
CR: "\r"
LF: "\n"
```

Then use it:

```yaml
- name: Something
  win_lineinfile:
    path: some_path
    line: |
      firstline{{ CR }}{{ LF }}
      secondline
```

In my case I use it to join strings from lists:

```yaml
public_keys:
  mdk:
    - ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
    - ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
  youpi:
    - ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
    - ssh-ed25519 AAAA...

authorized_keys: |
    ssh-ed25519 AAAA...
    {{ authorized_keys['mdk'] | join(LF) }}
```